# PHP file upload: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I've a big problem I'm working on for days now. My file upload in PHP does not work for the following reason.

**Here are some parts of my code:**

```
# Upload file1
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ev_ap_file1']['tmp_name'], 'as-content/'.$_FILES['ev_ap_file1']['name']);
# Upload file2
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ev_ap_file2']['tmp_name'], 'as-includes/css/'.$_FILES['ev_ap_file2']['name']);
```

**Infos about the files**

```
Array
(
    [ev_ap_file1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.php
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpfQIobp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 0
        )

[ev_ap_file2] => Array
    (
        [name] => test.css
        [type] => text/css
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpnQqf5T
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 0
    )
)
```

**And finally the error message I get:**

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(as-content/test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/steuben-schule.de/httpdocs/steu-admin/action/a_page.php on line 47
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpfQIobp' to 'as-content/test.php' in /var/www/vhosts/steuben-schule.de/httpdocs/steu-admin/action/a_page.php on line 47
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(as-includes/css/test.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/steuben-schule.de/httpdocs/steu-admin/action/a_page.php on line 49
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpnQqf5T' to 'as-includes/css/test.css' in /var/www/vhosts/steuben-schule.de/httpdocs/steu-admin/action/a_page.php on line 49
> Dev Exit enabled.

I already tried a lot of solutions and nothing worked. I'm the owner of the directory and of course it exist.

Thank you for your help!
Greetings, Arne

Comment: Are your destination dirs created?

Comment: The dirs are created and have 777 permissions. Finally that's the complete path.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Cases

> - Make sure have folder exist or you have enough permission to create new folder you are trying to move your file.
> - Folder [You want to move] must have write permission.
> - Apache user must have access of /tmp or temporary directory (set in php.ini "tmp_path").
> - Make sure server is not running out of memory`
> - Make sure file is not bigger than max_upload_size parameter

Comment: Thank you for your help. The folder was created with 777 permissions and still exist with another files in it.

Comment: Futhermore the server isn't running out of memory and the files are not bigger than 1kb.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, if the Apache user has access of the temporary directory because I cannot access the php.ini because I'm not the owner of the server and only have access to Plesk with restricted permissions. Can I get any informations with phpinfo about that?

Comment: Looks like your File size is 0 (Zero).

Comment: It may possible directory you want to upload has that same file exist and you don't have sufficient privileges to update it.

Comment: The file size is about 16 bytes, that's is why there is a 0. Oh, I'll update the script soon and rename the files automatically.

Comment: The script was updated and the error's still exist. It's impossible that the file already exist. Again: I'm not sure if I've enough permission to upload files. Can I get any informations with phpinfo about that?

Comment: Make sure in your parent and sub directory both have enough permission to write, and you can directory permission in plesk panel > Websites & Domains > File Manager and go to directory you want to check